# How to append an element with jQuery unless it exists already?

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery function that appends a `span` labelled "optional" to a label if no option is set in the select box.

```
function setLabel() {
    var label=$('label[for=person_address]');
    if ($('select#person_organisation_id').val().length != 0) {
      label.append(' <span>— optional</span>');     
    } else {
  label.children().remove();            
  } 
}
```

Right now this adds a new span to the label every time I select a new option. How can I check if a span already exists and only add a span if there is none already?

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following:

```
label.not(":has(span)").append(" <span>— optional</span>");
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have multiple span in label use following code

```
function setLabel() {
    var label=$('label[for=person_address]');
    if ($('select#person_organisation_id').val().length != 0) {
        if(label.find(".optional").length == 0){
               label.append(' <span class="optional">— optional</span>'); 
        }    
    } else {
  label.children().remove();            
  } 
}
```